# How to setup a grid as template for an Items control?

Tags: wpf, grid, itemscontrol, itemssource

I'm trying to create an `ItemsControl` that uses a grid as its `ItemsPanel` in such a way that it has two columns, where the first columns width is the width of the widest item in that column, and has as may rows needed to display all the items

Basically, I want the following, but somehow within an `ItemsControl` so that I can bind to a collection of objects:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding Items[0].Header}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Items[0].Content}" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Label Content="{Binding Items[1].Header}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Items[1].Content}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Label Content="{Binding Items[2].Header}" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Items[2].Content}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

Edit : Rachels answer worked great, here is a working example.

(I moved the Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" to the ItemsPanel, not sure if Rachel meant to put it in the ItemTemplate (which didn't work))

```
namespace WpfApplication23
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public Window1()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>() 
            { 
                new Item(){ Header="Item0", Content="someVal" },
                new Item(){ Header="Item1", Content="someVal" },
                new Item(){ Header="Item267676", Content="someVal" },
                new Item(){ Header="a", Content="someVal" },
                new Item(){ Header="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", Content="someVal" },
                new Item(){ Header="ccccccc", Content="someVal" } 
            };

            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication23.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ColumnOne" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Content}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: A perfect use case for @Rachel's [Grid Attached Properties](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/)

Comment: Im not sure how that would work, as an item in my example contains both the Header and the content.

Comment: use your imagination dude. Otherwise give me an hour or so to finish my work here and I can create an example for you.

Comment: The Grid AttachedProperties that @HighCore mentions would work for a dynamic number of rows, however it wouldn't work for the rest of what you're trying to do. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16609497/302677) for more details why. :)

Comment: Commenting on your working example; setting `ItemsPanelTemplate` is not needed since `StackPanel` is default value anyways. You can simplify your solution a bit by setting `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` directly to the `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are multiple problems here for an `ItemsControl`:

- Getting your first column to match the width of the largest item
- Generating a dynamic number of rows
- Generating more than one item for each iteration of the `ItemsControl`

The last one is really the biggest problem, because an `ItemsControl` wraps each `ItemTemplate` in a `ContentPresenter`, so there is no default way of creating more than one item in the panel for each Iteration of the `ItemsControl`. Your end result would look like this:

```
<Grid>
    ...

    <ContentPresenter>
        <Label Content="{Binding Items[0].Header}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Items[0].Content}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Label Content="{Binding Items[1].Header}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Items[1].Content}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Label Content="{Binding Items[2].Header}" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Items[2].Content}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

My best suggestion would be to create an `ItemTemplate` that contains a 1x2 `Grid`, and use `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` to make the width of the first column shared. (The `ItemsPanelTemplate` would remain the default `StackPanel`.)

This way, the end result would look like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ColumnOne" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding Header}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Content}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ColumnOne" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding Header}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Content}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPresenter>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Please note that `Grid.IsSharedScope="True"` should be set on the parent container, *not on the children grids*. That (otherwise very good and helpful) answer left me confused with that `IsSharedScope` property.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <GridViewColumn 
                Header="" 
                Width="Auto" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Header}"/>
            <GridViewColumn 
                Header="" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

the ColumnHeaderContainerStyle hides the GridViewHeader

Comment: Thankyou, but I didn't really want the column sliders or the selection that is present in a listview