# Insert list of user control to a specific column and rows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a user control which contains a list of items. I want to display them like the below image.

[image]
The grid has 4 columns but numbers of rows depend on the count of the items. I tried the Uniform grid and Grid but I could not find a solution.

My XAML

```xml
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Foods}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UniformGrid  Width="750" >
                <local:FoodItemControl />
            </UniformGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When I use the uniform grid it shows items vertically. Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596579/how-to-setup-a-grid-as-template-for-an-items-control

Comment: How about a wrappanel?  like this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33327.wpf-wrappanel-itemspanel-last-of-line.aspx.

Comment: @Vernou Yes but using wrap panel is a better choice in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a wrappanel with Orientation horizontal:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
```

This will arrange content in the panel left to right and down.

Note that this is the itemspaneltemplate.  As in the template for the container which will hold a number of usercontrols and arrange them like your picture.

In your markup you have itemtemplate.

The itemtemplate provide just your usercontrol.

```
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <local:FoodItemControl  Width="200"  />
           </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

It seems unlikely that you will want 4 usercontrols in a row that are 750 pixels wide each. Above, I have the width as 200 but that is just an arbitrary guess.